# Not able to create mock object using mocker

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

I am trying to create mock object for unit testing but somehow always actual object is called.
Below is the code for reference:-

1. utility_functions.py

```
import os
import json


def get_module_configurations(key):
    config = os.getcwd()
    config = config + "\\xyz.json"
    with open(config) as f:
        module_config = json.load(f)
    module_config = module_config[key]
    return module_config
```

2. load_class

```
from importlib import import_module
from inspect import isclass, isabstract


def load_module(data):
    package_path = data['Package']
    module_name = data['ModuleName']
    class_name = data['ClassName']

    try:
        module_name = str(module_name.split('.py')[0])
        module = import_module('.' + module_name, package_path)

    except Exception as error:
        pass

    try:
        _class = getattr(module, class_name)
    except Exception as error:
        pass
    if isclass(_class) and not (isabstract(_class)):
        return _class
    else:
        return None
```

3. function1.py

```
import load_class
from utility_functions import get_module_configurations


def load_helpers(task_name):
    module = get_module_configurations(task_name)
    cls = load_class.load_module(module)
    return cls
```

4. test_function.py

```
import pytest
from function1 import load_helpers


def test_mock(mocker):
    class_to_load = {"Package": "Test", "ModuleName": "default_class.py", "ClassName": 
                    "DefaultClass"}
    mocker.patch('function1.load_helpers', return_value= class_to_load)
    result = load_helpers('c')
    assert result is not None
```

Since I am mocking, load helpers should not be called but it always calls actual implementation saying path is invalid.

I am missing something basic but cannot figure out what.
Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are importing the function into your module (`from function1 import load_helpers`), you need to patch it as if it was part of it. This means that instead of...

```py
mocker.patch('function1.load_helpers', return_value=class_to_load)
```

...you should use...

```py
mocker.patch('test_function.load_helpers', return_value=class_to_load)
```

PS: I assume that you are just practicing mocking because otherwise your test function doesn't make sense.

Comment: I just used the part which was giving issue not the entire test. That worked, One question I wanted to ask is as the method is present in the function1 why is required to create mock with test_function?

Comment: You need to patch it as if it was part of the module **where it is imported**. The fact that in your example it's imported in the test module itself, makes it a rather unusual case because typically the function would be imported into some other non-test module and you'd patch that. You didn't post a real code example but let's say that if you imported `load_helpers` in *utility_functions.py*, you'd patch `utility_functions.load_helpers` in your test function.